# Proving 2 statements in elementary set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have 2 questions for homework that I think I know the answer but im really not sure. 
We are given that f:A→B is a function and C1 and C2 are subsets of A

.

Now I need to prove if this 2 statement are true or false:
1. If f(C1)⊂f(C2) then C1⊂C2 .
2. If f is an injective function and f(C1)⊂f(C2), then C1⊂C2 .

Comment: "proving" and not "pro**o**ving". English has : "to prove" and "proof" alas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do (1), you then get the point and *you do* (2):

Take the function $\;f:\{1,2,3,4\}\to\{a,b,c\}\;$ defined as $\;f(1)=f(2)=a\,,\,f(3)=b\,,\,f(4)=c\;$, and now take the subsets

$$C_1=\{1,4\}\;,\;\;C_2=\{2,4\}\implies f(C_1)=\{a,c\}\subset\{a,c\}=F(C_2)$$

yet $\;C_1\rlap{\;\,/}\subset C_2\;$ (nor the other way around, by the way)